# Template does not exist django flatpages

Tags: django, django-flatpages

Made a cms project in django, but its not loading my default template for flatpages, attached are the images.

Thanks

```
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.flatpages',
]

SITE_ID = 1

MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.flatpages.middleware.FlatpageFallbackMiddleware'
]
```

[Error page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/md4kK.png)

[Directory structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tvoYB.png)

[Admin](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3MDN.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you set the `TEMPLATES` in your `settings.py`? Check and set the `TEMPLATES.DIR` setting to your folder path:

```
TEMPLATES = {
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
}
```

Moreover, you can move the `templates` folder inside the `cms` folder. In this case, be sure that `TEMPLATES.APP_DIRS` is set to `True`.

```
cms
+- cms/
 +- templates/
  +- flatpages/
   +- default.html
 +- views.py
 +- other django stuff...
+- db.sqlite3
```

You can find more information in the official documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/templates/#configuration

Answer (score 1):

You need to do some changes in your settings file.

Declare a variable `BASE_DIR` as:

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
```

Then edit the `DIRS` in the `TEMPLATES` as:

```
'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
```

Also keep the template files of cms inside cms folder like:

cms>templates>cms>flatpages